# show and hide span from parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

On click of **View All Descriptions**, I should be able to show the  following div's and change the **View All Descriptions** content to **hide all descriptions** and when clicked it again it  should be able to  hide the following div's and change the clickable content to **"View all descriptions"**

```css
.hiddenComments {
  display: none;
  padding: 5px;
}
.showComments {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row outer-part col-md-offset-1">
  <div class="col-md-12 TechDiscSelectAll" id="divSelectAll_DRILLING">
    <a id="lnkViewAll_DRILLING" class="NoWrap">View All Descriptions</a>
  </div>

  <div class="row padding-4">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <span class="hiddenComments">Sample text;</span>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="row padding-4">
    <div class="col-md-12">

      <span class="hiddenComments">sample text</span>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: How can *we* do that??  Do you mean how can YOU do that?  What have YOU tried?  We're not just some service that will write code for you.  We're here to help you understand, but you have to put a little effort in. edit: how am I saying this to a person with almost 3k rep?  You'd think you would understand how things work around here by now...

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp

Comment: @wazaaaap at least post the jquery site documentation not w3schools :(

Comment: Funny how many of your questions start with *"How to...?"* http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/28/famous-question?userid=158008

Answer (score 0):

If you will be more specific i will be able to help you better..Meanwhile take a look at this:

```
$('a').click(function () {
   $('a').text('Hide');

    $(".hiddenComments").addClass('showComments');
    $('.hiddeComments').removeClass('hideComments');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

No css needed, no extra classes, just jquery events. Next time read about jquery documentation before ask here, it will be better for your learning. https://api.jquery.com/

```js
$('#lnkViewAll_DRILLING').click(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      var text = ($this.text() != 'Hide All Descriptions') ? 'Hide All Descriptions' : 'Show All Descriptions';
      $this.text(text);

      $(".comments").toggle();
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="jquery" data-semver="2.1.4" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row outer-part col-md-offset-1">
    <div class="col-md-12 TechDiscSelectAll" id="divSelectAll_DRILLING">
      <a id="lnkViewAll_DRILLING" class="NoWrap">View All Descriptions</a>
    </div>
    <div class="row padding-4">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <span class="comments">Sample text;</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row padding-4">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <span class="comments">sample text</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using:

```
divElement.childNodes[0].style.display = "inline";//show element
divElement.childNodes[0].style.display = "none";//hide element
```

The first one shows the first element inside a parent element, and the second one hides it. Hope I helped!

Answer (score -1):

Since you haven't really given any specific on your code, or what you've tried.. look into jQuery hide() method. [Jquery Hide Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) This will get you moving in the right direction

Comment: Why was I downvoted, he asked how, and I gave him a link to the documentation? If anything it helps him the most since there was no specifics at all

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but answering a question as poor as this one will just encourage the OP, and is not helpful to anyone else. It is best to request that the OP improves the question before answering

Comment: But if the user is asking how to do this with no set specifics, shouldn't a point in the right direction be as valid as any other answer? This is one of the problems with the community. Instead of just leaving the answer alone someone felt the need to say it hurt as an answer? I call BS

Comment: Actually, this is not the point of Stackoverflow. Maybe another stack exchange site.... But SO is meant for specific issues, not broad questions

Comment: So "where do I start if I have this" is not a specific question?

Comment: I'm not trying to be mean. I'm just stating what's SO designed for. **Questions seeking debugging help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.** Read here the docs: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic